# setTimeout() not working with onClick

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, timeout

I have a button (in apDiv126) which when clicked shows an image (which is in apDiv129)

```
<div id="apDiv126"style="display:none"><input name="Yep" type="image" src="accept.png" onClick=toggle_div('apDiv129');time('apDiv129');"></div>

<div id="apDiv129"style="display:none"><img src="request confirmed.png" width="370" height="215"></div>
```

When the button is clicked it should show the image (with toggle_div) and then execute the time function:

Here's the time function:

```
function time(id) {
    var divelement = document.getElementById(id);
    setTimeout(function(){
        divelement.style.display = 'none'
    }, 2);
}
```

The time fucntion should make the image disapear after 2 seconds. However when I try my webpage, it doesn't even display the image. toggle_div is working, because when I remove `time('apDiv129');` from onClick, the image appears.

I've also tried to call toggle_div in the timeout anonymous function but it doesn't work too.

My question is: onClick executes the functions in the order that is given? Is there a possibility timeout is starting the "countdown" when I open the page?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout

Answer (score 6):

The second argument on `setTimeout` is the time in milliseconds, try `2000` instead. And to answer your question: `setTimeout` begins counting from the instant it is called, not from when the page loads. (unless within an onLoad event handler)

Comment: It works now, that was the problem, I read somewhere that the time was in seconds so I assumed it had nothing to do with that. Thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 2):

Timeout function accepts time in milliseconds...
set 2000 instead of 2...

```
function time(id) {
  var divelement = document.getElementById(id);
  setTimeout(function(){
  divelement.style.display = 'none'
  }, 2000);
 }
```

Comment: That was the problem, thank you :D